# While installing lite-server it show vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json, lite-server

- lite-server@2.5.4
  added 1 package from 2 contributors and audited 340 packages in 20.502s
  found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

*After running 'npm audit fix' it shows*

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 4 vulnerabilities in 340 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

**And an package-lock.json file has been created**

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @DanO Why package-lock.json file has been created? The tutorial from where I was studying this, no such file was created. And afterwards I tried to staging area of my git repository. It showed me this warning.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 after working for whole day. This should work for other Linux distros

```
1) Run following command for globally using lite-server
```

```
     sudo npm install lite-server -g
```

2. Your package.json file should contain

```
     "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
     }
```

and scipt should look like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
```

```
3) For development mode run following
```

```
     sudo npm i lite-server --save-dev
```

4. Local server could started using npm command

```
     npm start
```